# Bulma CSS modal not showing

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bulma

I am using Bulma as my CSS framework, and while trying to use their modals, they aren't styled at all, as if I'm missing something.

[image]

The overlay is there, and `x` button seems in place and visible, but the content is greyed out.

I am using this code:

```
<body>

<div id="modal-id" class="modal is-active">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        Any other Bulma elements you want
    </div>
    <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</div>

</body>
```

All other Bulma elements are working.

Note: I am not asking about JS part and how to actually show the modal on click. I am having pure CSS issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But this is currently being shown and there is no problem!

if you want a Design, like a card, change `.modal-content` div to this:

```
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body">
      YOUR CONTENT
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
      <button class="button">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
```